# How to get all combinations from a random sample list

Tags: python

I am having an issue trying to get all of the combinations of two random sample lists.

I have two lists, one contains all 10k golfers and the other contains all 7k golfers. What I want to do is get all the lineup combinations of golfers (6 golfers per lineup) where I include 2 golfers from the 10k range and 4 golfers from the 7k range.

Currently the list that contains the combinations only includes 6 combinations and I am assuming it's because of a mistake is in the for loop but I am not sure what to set the range as in order to get all combinations:

```
tenKRange = []
sevenKRange = []
lineup = []

with open('combinations.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[1]) >= 10000:
            tenKRange.append(row)
        ...
        elif int(row[1]) < 8000 and int(row[1]) >= 7000:
            sevenKRange.append(row)
  

for n in range(len(combinations(random.sample(tenKRange,2) + (random.sample(sevenKRange,4)), 6))):
    lineup.append(list(combinations(random.sample(tenKRange,2) + (random.sample(sevenKRange,4)), 6)))
```

Comment: IIUC, you want to find all possible ways to pick 2 golfers out of 10k, and 4 out of 7k, and then get the product of these two sets?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's correct

Comment: Why are you taking random samples? If Pranav is right, then you actually don't want that at all. Please provide a [mre] with example input, working code, and example output. For input, if `sevenKRange` and `tenKRange` are being created correctly, then the CSV code is irrelevant to the problem; just give us the Python data (or rather, a minimal sample). To get working code, include the imports. You're using `itertools.combinations`, right? For the output, I ask because a lot of people say "combinations" when they actually mean "Cartesian product", so we gotta make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to find all possible ways to pick 2 golfers out of 10k, and 4 out of 7k, and then get the product of these two sets? If this is the case, you need to do it in those steps:

```
import itertools 

sel_10k = itertools.combinations(tenKRange, 2)
sel_7k = itertools.combinations(sevenKRange, 4)

lineup = [p + q for p, q in itertools.product(sel_10k, sel_7k)]
```

With example lists that contain fewer elements:

```
tenKRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sevenKRange = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]
```

this gives the expected lineups:

```
[(1, 2, 101, 102, 103, 104),
 (1, 2, 101, 102, 103, 105),
 (1, 2, 101, 102, 103, 106),
 (1, 2, 101, 102, 103, 107),
 (1, 2, 101, 102, 104, 105),
 ...
 (2, 8, 101, 103, 104, 105),
 (2, 8, 101, 103, 104, 106),
 (2, 8, 101, 103, 104, 107),
 (2, 8, 101, 103, 105, 106),
 (2, 8, 101, 103, 105, 107),
 ...
 (9, 10, 103, 104, 105, 106),
 (9, 10, 103, 104, 105, 107),
 (9, 10, 103, 104, 106, 107),
 (9, 10, 103, 105, 106, 107),
 (9, 10, 104, 105, 106, 107)]
```

Comment: Spot on. Nice break into 2-steps.